# Environment.MachineName and IP address in a web farm in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip-address, web-farm

1. Will the following line of code always return a unique machine name in a web farm, or it could sometimes return nothing/duplicate name?

   string currentRequestWebFarmNode = Environment.MachineName;
2. Also, is IP address for each web farm node obtained by using code below going to be unique always in that web farm? My guess is yes, but not sure.

   string currentRequestWebFarmNode = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.Url.Host).AddressList(0).ToString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to these questions will depend on your hosting environment. The fastest way to find out is probably to try it.

Comment: I was looking for a fool-proof way of obtaining a 'unique' value for either IP address or machine name in a web farm. You think that may not be possible?

Comment: I actually strongly suspect that it is possible. I just can't tell you what either of those expressions will return because it's based on how those machines are configured.

Comment: Ok. FYI - I was developing a generic framework where I needed to get a unique name for the current request's web server. That means my code will have to work in all web farms.

Comment: Environment.MachineName seems like a reasonable name, but there's no way to guarantee uniqueness.